# Extract the consecutive words from the middle of a string in R

Tags: r, regex, string

Ok, so I'm new to regexpr and my brain is about to fry. What I would like to do is extract words two and three from a string. For example:

```
sentence <- "Certified 2017 Mazda CX-5 AWD Touring"
TheFunction(sentence)
```

should return "2017 Mazda"

My initial attempt is using something like:

```
sub("\\s\\S+\\s\\S+\\s", "\\1", sentence)
```

but is failing miserably. My idea is to find the first pattern that matches "space-word-space-word-space"

Comment: See https://ideone.com/cra6QZ

Comment: I'd use `strsplit(sentence, split = "\\s")[[1]][2:3]`

Comment: `stringr::word(x, 2, 3)`

Comment: `gsub('(^\\w+\\s)(\\w+\\s\\w+)(^|\\s.*)', '\\2', sentence)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strsplit then paste the 2nd and 3rd word together

```
paste(strsplit(sentence, split = '\\s')[[1]][2:3], collapse = " ")
```